# how to safe use your passwords for mysql and nodemailer inside your server script

Tags: node.js, express, passwords

i am building an app using node express for server code.

as you can see in my title i am using mysql npm and nodemailer npm.

my code to connect to them looks like this:

```
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
  host     : '...',
  user     : '...',
  password : '...',
  database : '...'
});

var transport = nodemailer.createTransport("SES", {
AWSAccessKeyID: "...",
AWSSecretKey: "..."
});
```

as you can see instead of the ... my actuall passwords are in this file.

is it ok to actually write my passwords inside my server.js file?

if this file will get to someone he will have my passwords... although no one should have the possiblity to access my file since it is in my server but still it appears abit odd to me.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is considered best not to store password in any file, code or configuration, that goes into source control.

The alternative is usually setting them an environment variables.